# What is Doctrine based on when choosing INSERT or UPDATE?

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm

In my application, in a really precise case when I try to update an entity with Doctrine, this failed because "Key already exists".

In fact, Doctrine tries to `INSERT INTO` instead of `UPDATE` and I don't understand why.

To understand why Doctrine doesn't choose the right way to do, I want to know what  is Doctrine based on when choosing `INSERT INTO` or `UPDATE` ?

It seems to not be based on ID, so on what ?

Maybe it will help to find the answer: I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork.html

Comment: Can you provide us a code sample ? We won't be able to help you without a [mcve]

Comment: @LP154 I can't, this is why I ask the question: I don't identify a pattern to reproducte it.
The fact is that the update datas comes from the request payload so maybe Doctrine does't detect that it must be an update ?

Comment: Have you created and populated the entity manually without fetching it through Doctrine first?

Comment: Yes i did this.

Comment: @LeCintas you need to fetch the entity first so Doctrine knows about the entity and how to calculate changes, or merge your entity into the EM. INSERT/UPDATE decision can't rely on presence of identifier as you may have new entity with manually assigned id that requires insertion.

Comment: I did a `$this->em->merge();` and the entity has a `@ORM\id()`
I found the answer of my problem: the id of a child entity of my "main" entity were not set on update, so Doctrine decided to create a new "main" entity entry to satisfy the relation.